# Calling Codeigniter Controller function inside the jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to specify the controller path inside the .ajax function of jquery.

```
type:'POST',
                    url:"<?php site_url('login/validate'); ?>",
                    //dataType: "json",
                    data:data1,

                    success: function (response){

                            //alert (response);

                            $("span.error").html('Congrats! You are successfully registered with our site').addClass('error');
                            //window.location="site";

                        },
```

Currently i am doing this but the path is taken as a string. Its going into the success function i dont know whay? but when i alert the response it gives an error of "Disallowed key characters"

Comment: And what is code inside the controller and what data are you sending?

Comment: The code you have presented in your example, where is it placed? In a view (.php) file or in a Javascript (.js) file?

Comment: the code is placed in the .js file and i am validating the form fields and want to send the data to the php controller after validation to be inserted into the database

Comment: @Mudi Did you check my answer?I think it will help you

Comment: its going into the success function and when i want to alert the response it gives me the error "disallowed key characters"

Comment: if you want to add php code to JS file, you need to serve the JS from a PHP file. Add a controller and change its header information and then add the JS in it's view and include the controller URL instead of the JS file.

Answer (score 1):

This was due to `url:"<?php site_url('login/validate'); ?>",`   create  only `url:"",`You need to `echo` the url.

```
  url:"<?php site_url('login/validate'); ?>",
```

Change to

```
  url:"<?php echo site_url('login/validate'); ?>",
```

OR

```
 url:"<?= site_url('login/validate'); ?>",
```

Comment: i have tried this and chk on the firefox debugger it is still taking that url as a string :(

Comment: var url="<?= site_url('login/validate'); ?>"; and try url:url,

Answer (score 1):

Change your line

```
 url:"<?php site_url('login/validate'); ?>",
```

To

```
 url:"<?php echo site_url('login/validate'); ?>",
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing

```
url:"<?php site_url('login/validate'); ?>",
```

You need to do

```
url:"<?php echo site_url('login/validate'); ?>",
```

Because you want to echo out the return value of site_url

**Note:** The above won't work if you are attempting to call a PHP function from a .js file.  You will need to build the JavaScript from a .php file.  Alternatively you could declare a global JS variable with the result of site_url before you call your JS file and access it that way.